# laravel 9 error in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, database, many-to-many, laravel-9

I am new to Laravel and I just started learning php and laravel 9 material for many to many relationship, But I am having trouble with an error, what I want to ask is, on the actual page, it should display student data, but it is displaying error - the array is empty, I've checked for this error, but confused.
[text](https://github.com/ubur/errror.git)

Comment: duplicated description, add more details like the path of the error.